# get Object by key in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of domains.

```
{
    id: "domains",
    links: [
        {
            href: "https://www.google",
            name: "google"
        },
        {
            href: "https://www.facebook.com",
            name: "facebook"
        }
    ]
}
```

what´s the most effective way to get "google" should I use filter?

Comment: If you expect only one result use `Array.prototype.find`. `domains.links.find(({ name }) => name === 'google');`. If you expect multiple matches, use `Array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: thank you. that´s what I´m looking for